# How do I pass the string from powershell's out-string as an argument to get-content / cat (directly)?

Tags: powershell

I want to basically do this:

```
Get-Childitem -Recurse -filter "* *" -Force | foreach-object {
  get-childitem $_ | select-object fullname |
    Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -wrap |
    out-string | cat $input
}
```

Cat here is an alias of powershell's get-content I think, but I frequently use it after writing bash code. I don't think that's the problem. It gives the error:

```
cat : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take
+ ... me | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -wrap | out-string | cat $input }
```

Trying `get-content`:

```
Get-Childitem -Recurse -filter "* *" -Force | foreach-object {
  get-childitem $_ | select-object fullname |
    Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -wrap |
    out-string | Get-Content $input
}
```

Similar error:

```
Get-Content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does
not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

I also tried removing `out-string`.

Searching for the answer to this question is how I arrived at `out-string`, but it didn't work. I'm curious to know how to do it without assigning a variable if feasible.

Comment: Judging by you comment on @mklement0's answer, what are you trying to do here? Can you explain in english? It's not apparent what you want to read from with the code sample alone.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest no its standalone

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do, and also don't use `$input` as a normal variable. It has a specific meaning as an automatic variable

Comment: Are you just trying to display the files returned by `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Im aware of what $input is, it's an automatic variable containing the standard output piped. I'm tasked with searching a large directory structure to find a folder with a space in the name. The folder contains a single file. The file name is long, deeply nested, and hard to type, hence trying to get its name dynamically and pass the path to `get-content` to print the contents cotaining my CTF flag.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my first comment but you said this was standalone, not part of a function that takes pipeline input, so `$input` is not valid in this context. If you want all arguments passed to a normal function or to a script, use the `$args` array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `cat` is an alias for [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) on Windows.

The only form of pipeline input `Get-Content` accepts are objects or strings representing *file paths*, whose content is then output.

This is not what [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) outputs (it generally outputs a *single, multi-line string*, which in your case is the string representation of the  *for-display*-formatted output produced by [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)).

Based on your comments, you're looking for something like this:

```
Get-Childitem -Recurse -Directory -Filter "* *" -Force | 
  Get-ChildItem -File |
    Get-Content
```

As an aside: the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) is only defined in specific contexts, and cannot be used as a command argument the way you tried. Specifically, `$input` represents *outside* pipeline / stdin input for the *entire scope* at hand, not what flows through a given pipeline.

Comment: I actually want to print the file content, that's why I'm using `cat $input` where `$input` is the file path. How do I pass the output as an argument to get-content?

Comment: @mklement0 I don't think there's anything more I can add that you haven't covered, but why are you piping `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem` a second time? Also, `Get-Content` is picky and will error if a directory is returned by `Get-ChildItem`, might want to add `-File` as an argument

Comment: "the automatic $input variable is only defined in specific contexts" yes, isn't that specific context when STDOUT is piped? like `my-command | out-string | echo $input `

Comment: Just to repeat what I replied to @BendertheGreatest above: I'm aware of what $input is, it's an automatic variable containing the standard output piped. I'm tasked with searching a large directory structure to find a folder with a space in the name. The folder contains a single file. The file name is long, deeply nested, and hard to type, hence trying to get its name dynamically and pass the path to `get-content` to print the contents cotaining my CTF flag.

Comment: My thought process here was, as you said "Get-Content, unlike the cat Unix utility, does not support pipeline input except strings or objects representing file paths", so `my-command | out-string | echo $input` where `$input` is an automatic variable representing the output of `out-string`, which I want to pass as an argument to `get-content`

Comment: Ok, I think I see, perhaps I misunderstood what out-string does.

Comment: @J.Todd As for `$input`: It represent the current scope's _outside_ pipeline / stdin input, and not what's flowing through the pipeline at hand.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest: The intent is to have the first `Get-ChildItem` find a _directory_, whose _files_ the second `Get-ChildItem` then enumerates.

Comment: thank you. Your code works perfectly, thank you, but please add @BendertheGreatest 's suggestion of -File with your second `get-childitem`, it prevents errors.

Comment: Good point re `-File`, @BendertheGreatest - thanks: added to the answer.

Comment: @J.Todd Glad to hear it; my pleasure. Re `-File`: done.

Comment: Ah you've already done it. This answers my question. It's confusing using powershell compared to, say, python, I'll say. To arrive at the answer you gave I have to completely change the way I think about passing data output around, I can't just pass properties places in a straight-forward way. The result actually looks elegant, but.... different from traditional programming.

Comment: @J.Todd, yeah, PowerShell takes some getting used to, but once you understand the fundamentals, it affords great power (no pun intended).

Comment: @mklement0, why not use the `-Directory` switch to `Get-ChildItem`? I don't recognize `"* *"` as a special globbing pattern, for me it returns objects with a space in the name

Comment: @mklement0 don't want to steal your thunder but you could reduce the pipeline use with `Get-ChildItem -File **/** | Get-Content`. For larger filesets this might be desirable to reduce memory consumption of the session

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, re `-Directory`: I originally wasn't sure if only directories or files too would need to be matched in the first step, but now that we know that it's only directories, adding `-Directory` makes good sense (which, as you've noticed, I've already done).

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, re `-File **/**`: I don't understand how that would help, given that folders whose name matches `'* *'` have to be found anywhere in the subtree (`-Directory`), followed by enumerating all files in those matching folders.

Comment: Sorry, I botched that expression a bit. The glob pattern would be `"* */**"`. This would get any files underneath a directory with space in the name. The caveat with this though is it will recurse all the way down, but so will using `-Directory -Recurse`

Comment: @BendertheGreatest: That doesn't work on Windows (and, on Unix-like platforms `**` is no different from just `*`, but it's good to know that (relative) _paths_ do work with `-Filter` there in principle - I did not know).

Comment: @mklement0 That glob works with `Get-ChildItem` to get all files in child directories with a space in the name (when coupled with `-File` to prevent directories from being returned). I'm on Windows and testing right now. This might be a similar case (I think it was you who mentioned the other day on a different answer) about ranges working with `gci` globs even though WIndows globbing in general doesn't support it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236458/discussion-between-mklement0-and-bender-the-greatest).

Answer (score 1):

See [@mklement's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68944258/584676) for how to achieve your end goal. Nothing much I can add on that point he hasn't covered.

---

However, your understanding of `$input` is a bit flawed. `$input` represents the pipeline input passed into a function or `ScriptBlock`, not the object being passed down the pipeline. You can't reference the pipeline data directly within the same expression, with a slight exception for cmdlets which support `$PSItem`/`$_` like `Where-Object` or `ForEach-Object` within their relevant `ScriptBlock` arguments.

If a cmdlet doesn't take pipeline input, assign what you would have piped to the cmdlet to a variable (or squeeze the expression with `()` where the parameter would be passed, optionally referencing a property if necessary from the expression result) and call the cmdlet with the previous output as an explicit parameter. @mklement's answer demonstrates this but I'll point it out here as well. For instance:

```
$files = ( Get-ChildItem $someDir -File ).FullName
Get-Content $files
```

Alternatively, to insert the expression result directly as a parameter without an intermediary variable:

```
Get-Content ( Get-ChildItem $someDir -File ).FullName
```

Additionally, `FileInfo` objects (the object type of files returned by `Get-ChildItem` `ToString`s to its `FullName` property, so referencing `.FullName` here is technically redundant. The following also works:

```
Get-Content ( Get-ChildItem -File )
```

Comment: I'm starting to understand. Powershell commands seem to sort of 'magically' find their desired input arguments from a passed in object. I'm used to traditonal programming and even traditional scripting where one needs to explicitly pass the desired arguments.

Comment: Yeah the pipeline is very powerful but it functions somewhat differently than the pipeline input you're probably used to processing. It took some getting used to for me as well

Comment: Thanks for your time. I literally have instructors in my class right now each getting paid close to six figures and couldn't explain what you two just graciously did for free. You guys are unsung heroes.

Comment: Thank you. To be fair, I have to keep on top of my skills to keep my salary ;) There's a joke about tenure in here somewhere O_o